# Archive.php isn't sorting posts from one single category

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination, wordpress-theming, categories

My archive page with added numeric pagination won't sort out the right category and instead shows posts from all the categories. Let's say the category is bananas (http://localhost/tkeblog/category/bananas/) and I get post from categories bananas, oranges and apples. Also the pagination system doesn't show posts with thumbail yet it works on my index.php page. What am I doing incorrectly to filter the posts by category?

```
<?php
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { $paged = get_query_var('paged'); }
elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { $paged = get_query_var('page'); }
else { $paged = 1; }

query_posts(array(
    'post_type'      => 'post', // You can add a custom post type if you like
    'paged'          => $paged,
    'posts_per_page' => 5
));

if ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="blogitem a">


<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

    <?php get_template_part('catalog',get_post_format()); ?>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="pagination">
    <?php my_pagination(); ?>
    </div>

</div>
 <?php else: ?>
<p>Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.</p>
 
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Since you're using "query_posts" (it's kind of overriding the category from the url) you should also specify the "category" parameter. (1) Get category: <?php $page_object = get_queried_object(); $category_id= $page_object->cat_ID; (2) add 'cat' => $category_id to your query_posts.

Comment: You're supposed to use the default query, not building one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take a look at the default [TwentyTwentyOne Wordpress theme `archive.php`](http://Source%20@%20https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-content/themes/twentytwentyone/archive.php) we can see that the archive template is just using a default loop to display all posts from all categories, not a custom query.

I believe this answers your question.

```
<?php
if( have_posts() ):
  while( have_posts() ): the_post();
    // ... template
  endwhile;
else:
    // ... fallback
endif; ?>
```

**If you want to customize the default query output** from the `archive.php` page, the best practice is to do it from your `function.php` page. You can use the the action hook filter `pre_get_posts`.

- Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/

> Fires after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run. Be aware of the queries you are changing when using the pre_get_posts action. Make use of conditional tags to target the right query.

```
<?php
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
  if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_archive() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) == 'post' ) {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post' ) );
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 12 );
      $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'date' ) );
      $query->set( 'order', array( 'ASC' ) );
    } else {
      $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
      $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'date' ) );
      $query->set( 'order', array( 'ASC' ) );
    };
  };
}; ?>
```